# Instance variables inside of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have model `Foo` with `bar` column.

I'm quite used to define instance methods of model like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
def do_smth
self.bar.capitalize!
end
end
```

But this is calling getter method on `self`, which should be just longer way of `@bar.capitalize!`.

As in Rails some things are hidden from eye (such as initializing `Base` class) I'm not sure. Will it work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you just mean writing @bar.capitalize! differently then you really should not do it. The whole point of using Rails is doing things "The Rails Way", which is fast, standardized, and everyone can understand it.

Comment: @Helsing, how writing self.something is faster than writing @something? Besides, I don't get why it is needed to call getter method on self, if each instance holds variable for each column. Actually, it should process faster than using self.

Comment: @JoeHalfFace actually in your case the fastest way would be to write it without `self` as in just `bar.capitalize!` because if `bar` is not a locally defined variable then it is automatically assumed to be an instance method.(I think). Anyways, `self` is not needed at all

Comment: I meant the opposite. If you want to write @bar.foobar!, just do it that way instead of using self. But Kkulikovskis' way might be the best way

Comment: @Kkulikovskis, I didn't know that it works just without self. By the way, `@column_name` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a bit of confusion going on here so lets start from the top:

Ruby is all about message passing - when you call a method on an object the implicit recipient is the object itself:

```
def do_smth
  self.bar.capitalize!
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
def do_smth
  bar.capitalize!
en
```

So lets take the following example:

```
class Thing

  def initialize
    @foo = 1
  end

  def test
    foo # NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'
  end

  def test2
    @bar # nil
  end
end
```

So, why does this fail? Because in Ruby instance variables are scoped to the instance and only accessible by using the sigil `@`. Ruby does not automatically map `@foo` to `Thing#foo`. Instance variables  Ruby even lets you access uninitialized ivars (`@bar`).

That is unless we create an accessor:

```
class Thing

  def foo
    @foo
  end

  def test
    foo # nil
  end
end
```

Which can be done with the shorthand macros `attr_reader` and `attr_accessor`.

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :foo # read only
  attr_accessor :foo # rw

  def test
    foo # nil
  end
end
```

This can be quite confusing if you start with Rails without learning how Ruby does OOP since Active Record reads your database tables and creates getters and setters "magically" for all your model attributes.

One thing that you need to remember in that case is that using `@some_column` will not call any getter/setter methods. Which can cause issues with the Rails dirty state tracking and in cases like date columns which typecast in the setter.